# How to calculate this integral involving trigonometric expression: $\int\frac{\ x^2+20}{{(x\sin x+5\cos x)}^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

$$\int\frac{\ x^2+20}{{(x\sin x+5\cos x)}^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

What should be the first thought for such a question?

Comment: My first thought is "half-angle substitution." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Comment: I doubt this has an elementary antiderivative

Comment: If there is an antiderivative, my first thought would be to exploit quotient rule and assume the answer was of the form $\frac{f(x)}{x\sin x +\cos x}$ and solve for $f$